# NSIndexPath and objectAtIndex in didSelectRowAtIndexPath crashes?

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsindexpath

I am working on a small iOS project, with a UITableView.

I made a table and put some content in it:

```
-(void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *fileName = [testList objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    NSString *docsDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *testPath = [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];


    NSMutableDictionary *plistDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:testPath];
    [[cell textLabel] setText:[plistDict valueForKey:@"title"]];
}
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"indentifier"];
    if(cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"identifier"];
        [cell autorelease];
    }

    [self configureCell:cell forIndexPath:indexPath];

    return cell;
}
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSString *docsDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSArray *dirContents = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:docsDir error:nil];
    testList = [dirContents filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self ENDSWITH '.stest'"]];
    return [testList count];
}
```

This works fine. I have a table with some dummy content in it. But when i am adding this code:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [testTable deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    NSLog(@"%d",[indexPath row]);
    NSLog(@"%@",[testList objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]);
}
```

The iOS simulator crashes(its not quiting, but the app doesn't respond anymore) when i press a cell in the table. The cause of this is the next line:

```
 NSLog(@"%@",[testList objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]);
```

When i delete this line it works perfect. This log:

```
NSLog(@"%d",[indexPath row]);
```

Returns the row number, as normal.

The strange thing is that i do exactly the same in the configureCell Function:

```
NSString *fileName = [testList objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
```

But that works fine.

What is going wrong here?

Comment: also, loading from a file every time you refresh a cell is not desirable, i suspect your scrolling will suffer - - - that said, no need to optimize before you have it working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to retain `testList`. The following line in `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` does **not** retain it:

```
testList = [dirContents filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self ENDSWITH '.stest'"]];
```

`filteredArrayUsingPredicate` returns an object you do **not** own (according to the Object Ownership Policy). Since you are accesing the ivar `testList` directly, you need to claim ownership of the object by sending it a retain message (and release it at some point in the future).

Note that `testList = ...` and `self.testList = ...` are not the same. The former accesses the ivar directly while the later goes through the accessor of the property `testList` (if you have one). So, if you have a `testList` retain property, it is as simple as this:

```
self.testList = [dirContents filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self ENDSWITH '.stest'"]];
```

If you do **not** have a `testList` retain property, you can retain the object like this:

```
testList = [[dirContents filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self ENDSWITH '.stest'"]] retain];
```

I encourage you to use a property since they encapsulate memory management code and thus reduce boilerplate code.

Comment: You're a genius. Tnx the retain method works. And thanks for the manual about the owning of objects.

Comment: You are welcome! Remember to release it when you no longer need it or it will leak :)